# How to install the Offline help of LibreOffice in Flatpak

Tags: libreoffice, helpfile, flatpak

I have LibreOffice 6.2.2.2 installed as a Flatpak.
Everything works fine but when I go to the menu `Help` -> `LibreOffice Help` I get the message:

> LibreOffice Help Not Installed

How can I install the offline help for the Flatpak LibreOffice?

I managed to download the help package there: http://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/6.2.2/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_6.2.2_Linux_x86-64_deb_helppack_en-US.tar.gz (link found on the LibreOffice download page https://www.libreoffice.org/download).

The help package contains subfolders `/opt/libreoffice6.2/help/en-US/` and 
`/opt/libreoffice6.2/help/media/` with `*.html` help files and some other `*.js` files.

Is there a way one can use this package to install the offline help for the Flatpak LibreOffice installation?

PS: I'm aware that I need the help version for the corresponding LibreOffice version, and that the help language must match the LibreOffice UI language.

Comment: Do you mean snap? Flatpak is not available on Ubuntu, but Snap is.

Comment: @vanadium No, I mean Flatpak. It is available with Linux Mint.

Comment: I've been using LibreOffice flatpak version for some time.  Flatpak-s work reliably on Ubuntu.  I've not been able to install anything with snap versions.

Comment: I think this question is more of a Flatpak question.  Like, "_How to package the UK English UI to work with LibreOffice flatpak?_"

Answer (score 5):

In a terminal, enter:

```
sudo flatpak install flathub org.libreoffice.LibreOffice.Help
```

see:
https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/installing-offline-help-for-current-flatpak-installation/50319

Comment: No, don't use "sudo"; just <flatpak install flathub org.libreoffice.LibreOffice.Help>

Comment: FYI, As of today, 25-07-2023, flatpak no longer has the LibreOffice help files.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, LO is pointed to files that are not present. We need to put the correct files where LO expects them.

After years of no response from LibreOffice forum and this forum, and by tinkering, this is what worked for me in both Ubuntu 22 and Pop_OS 22:...

1). Go the LibreOffice webpage, find the section for help files, download the language and flatpak files you need. (In my case, UK language, Ubuntu, flatpak).

2). Use the file manager, Nautilus, to search for LibreOffice.Help. Note the location of this directory, and be ready to copy it and contents. In my case, the directory I needed to copy is: /org.libreoffice.LibreOffice.Help

3). In Nautilus, find this directory: /Home/.local/share/flatpak/runtime. To confirm you have the correct directory, look for this subdirectory: /org.libreoffice.LibreOffice.Locale

4/ Copy the /org.libreoffice.LibreOffice.Help directory ... into ...  /Home/.local/share/flatpak/runtime directory.

5/ Restart LO, and click the Help icon. If LO asks which app to use to open the help, choose your default browser (Firefox, in my case). voila! Offline help function works now.

hope this helps.

Comment: FYI, effective today, 25-07-2023, for the Flatpak LibreOffice 7.5 release, the notes above will not result in local offline help.  ........  The reason is LO 7.5 does not indicate where the help files should be stored. ........ The LO website has a help file for download, but gives no instructions where to place the help files. 
 Also, the unzipped files have completely different directories and names.